# How to create AWS S3 key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've set up an AWS S3 bucket, and it's working for transfers using the web UI, but I want to be able to use the "aws s3 sync" command. The only way I know how to use that command requires that I have an  aws_secret_access_key associated with the bucket. However, I have utterly failed to discover out how to create this key, or how to supply a key for use with this bucket.

Can someone tell me how to do this, or point me at the right piece of documentation, please?

Comment: Maybe this helps? [https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-access-key/](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-access-key/)

Comment: yes, it does. clearly my misunderstanding was that the key is created for the IAM user, not for the service to be accessed.

Now trying to work out how to grant a privilege to that user, but that's a separate question.

If you'd like to write that as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Nice to be of help :-) I prefer not to write link-only answers, and have nowhere near enough AWS know-how to summarize the process so... Please go ahead and write yours. I'm sure it'll be helpful for others in the future looking for the info :-)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you need to create an access key / secret key pair which is associated with an IAM user. You need to ensure the IAM user has appropriate permissions to access S3. If the user can access things in the console they're probably fine.

The [link above](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-access-key/) is appropriate for process.